# Java Swing app on MacOS over ssh throws headless exception

Tags: java, swing, headless, java-10

Well (sheepishly), my original post and title was a complete false alarm on my part. I use an ssh client on my Mac instead of the terminal app. Running a Java Swing app under that ssh client throws the headless exception, of course.

It can be fixed by using the command line option "-Djava.awt.headless=false".

Thanks for everyone's help and sorry for the time waster.

F.

Original, completely misleading post follows!

We've had a Java Swing app out "in the wild" for many years. We ship it as a jar file and non-technical users launch it by double clicking the jar. It gets updated regularly, most recently late last year using Java 8.

Recently a user reported that that app won't start up, and reported running Java 10. Sure enough, when I tested on Java 10 locally, starting via command line, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
```

I can confirm that I can successfully start the app via command line with "-Djava.awt.headless=false". Or I can accomplish the same thing with a "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" environment variable. Unfortunately neither of these options are a simple fix for the users, so we will presumably have to deploy a new version that sets the property in code.

The odd thing, and the reason I'm writing, is that I can find nothing about this on the net. I would think this would affect many, many applications. Am I missing something? Is this a bug? Or has Oracle documented this change somewhere? Or maybe if I recompile with Java 10 libraries this goes away?

Comment: *"Is this a bug?"* Check the [Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/).

Comment: I just wrote a short program that loads a web page headlessly in a JEditorPane and prints it to a file, using Java 10.0.2.  Of course, I used `-Djava.awt.headless=true`;  I assume `false` was a typo?

Comment: *"Or maybe if I recompile with Java 10 libraries this goes away?"* - Highly unlikely.  The change of behavior (if there really is one) will be in the libraries on the execution platform. Can you provide an MVCE that we can run on different Java platforms?

Comment: @VGR - No, not a typo. It's a GUI app, so I needed to set headless to false for it to start. Seems like the default for Java 10 is true, but wasn't in the past.

Comment: What operating system is the problem happening on? On Linux/Unix systems the default depends on the `DISPLAY` environment being set.

Comment: @FredToth I see that you've fixed the problem.  Can you post the solution as an answer below and accept it?